# Correct way of catching error in Promise objects

Tags: angular-promise

Ok so I am newbie in `Angularjs`,one of my current task is to code a `CRUD` functionality and I used the Promise to handle it.

```
dao.updateEntityCharSpecUseRelSql = function (paramField) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  .......
    }).catch(err => { reject(err)});// **my PM says, catching error is wrong**
}

module.exports = dao;
```

First, I thought, catch block is just alright because I am getting it from the Promise object which returns the error if something goes wrong.

But my Pm says, in order to use this, promises should have **`.then()`** first.

Is it really a bad practice to use the **`catch()`** without `then()`. What he propose is that instead, I should create a **`try & catch`** block inside the `Promise()` something like

```
new Promise (function(resolve, reject){
    try {
           resolve(something)
        }catch(err){
           reject(err)
        }
})
```

Please enlighten me for this.TIA

Comment: `reject(..)` doesn't seem to be in the scope of you `.catch(...)` block. Perhaps this is what your PM is getting at.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a step back.

When you create a `new Promise()` you are responsible to handle each **success** and **failure** case.

Who is calling your function (and getting your promise) is responsible to handle the response inside a `then()` callback, if the promise was successfully resolved, or a `catch()` callback, if the promise was rejected.

So, you **don't need to catch your own promise**.

Example:

```
function init() {
    getAsyncValues()
        .then(function (result) {
            // it will do something based on his business logic
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // it will do something based on his business logic
        });
}
function getAsyncValues() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ...
        resolve(SOME_VALUES);
        ...
        reject(SOME_ERRORS);
    })
}
```

---

And if your "promise handler" need to call async task before resolving something, you can wait his resolution like:

```
const examplePromise = new Promise(fuction (resolve, reject) {

    asyncTask() // executing an async task
        .then(function(result) {
            resolve(result);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            reject(error)
        });
})
```

Comment: thank you for  taking time answering my question, this is really helpful.